# Should I let my 5 year old watch the news?

Tags: television, age-appropriate, media

My 5 year old is very mature for his age. He has an amazing vocabulary and a great attention span. He is very interested in watching the evening news, but often times the news is filled with stories of murder and tragedy. We don't have a problem talking to him about these topics if necessary, but I'm concerned about letting him be exposed too much. What is a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: Have you considered READING the news together?  Choose a national paper that is known for its fairly unbiased coverage such as The Christian Science Monitor (but as appropriate for whichever country you are in) to avoid a focus on local murders and the like.

Comment: If you're in the US I am loving 'democracy now'. They have a podcast too. I don't think anyone should watch the evening news, it's all propaganda these days and very little actual information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree you want to be careful on how much tragedy you expose a 5 year old to, especially considering that the amount of coverage tragedies get on televised news programs far outweighs their frequency of occurrence in reality. You don't want your child to think that every hour there are murders, rapes, and other horrors happening in his neighborhood, nor do you want him to feel fearful of his own safety in his environment.

I presume your 5 year old is interested in watching the evening news because he sees you do it, and I wager that if you shifted your interest his interests would follow. Maybe the next time the news is on you can get up from the couch and say something like, "I think I'd rather go outside and kick the soccer ball around," or whatever, and he'll probably get up and follow you out.

If this is not the case and your child is genuinely drawn to news programs, I'd suggest picking and choosing what news shows he watches. While the [PBS News Hour](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/) certainly covers world tragedies, including wars, they don't focus on local matters or the type of "if it bleeds it leads" stories that are all to common on local news programs and, to an extent, national nightly news shows.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to lead with example, specifically to use the remaining daylight playing together. Adults can watch the news when the kids are asleep.

Comment: Good answer. We actually don't watch much news on TV, especially not local evening news, which I agree is disproportionately filled with murder, larceny, and burglary cases. I read most of my news online. We do occasionally turn it on and he is glued to it. Then is asks about 1-2 times a week to watch it, without any prompt.

Comment: Maybe he just likes feeling like a grown up, and that's something he ha decided is a grown up activity? Interesting!

Comment: *"the amount of coverage tragedies get on televised news programs far outweighs their frequency of occurrence in reality."* That is not possible unless they are making tragedies up.

Answer (score 12):

In the UK there is a programme on the BBC called [Newsround](http://news.bbc.co.uk/cbbcnews/default.stm), it has been going for decades, which is news specifically aimed and edited for children.

While it can be a little too focused on human interest stories and cuddly animals, it does also try to offer a simplified version of the news.

This would be a great sort of introduction - not just the subject matter, but the phrasing and words used to describe the issues.

Comment: I agree. Newsround is an excellent example of this. Usually they have the top or top two stories from the news followed by something about pandas or bears with unusual hats. The editorial team is held in very high standing within the BBC and it's considered quite a top posting internally. (Eg, anchors have unremarkably gone between Newsround and the top late-night news slots). Recently they've also done documentary specials covering things like racism in sport, knife crime, growing up in state care, children in war zones, etc. It is very well done (target age is 6-12). Can you receive it?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

When I was growing up, (I'm a baby boomer), I can still remember Dan Rather covering the Viet Nam war while my family and I watched from the dinner table. He was taking gun fire and I was riveted to the TV. This was during a time when there were only 3 network stations, no cable tv, no video games, cell phones, internet etc. This was pretty explicit coverage for the time. I can still remember how it made an impact on me.

My point is that, we didn't see alot of the stuff that children are seeing today.  There is alot more coverage of tragedy in the world in my estimation because there is alot more "coverage" i.e. infinitely more media outlets and channels for which it can be delivered

Yes, I'm going to make my point **promise**. Because of this your child is much more sophisticated than I was, or even you were at his age at filtering all of the information that is coming in. Watching the news with parental or adult supervision can only improve his maturity and understanding of the world we live in.

Good Luck.

Comment: Still, make sure that his filtering abilities are properly orchestrated.

Answer (score 3):

To be somewhat generic, I think that it really depends on what is covered in your area and how keen a person is to address the topics that are covered. Your approach seems good to me. The only thing that I might add is regular discussion of the topics, even when it doesn't seem necessary... just to get an idea of what he is processing.

I know children who while intelligent, won't talk much about recent happenings without being prompted. I've found that initiating discussion can redirect the *"secrecy" - for lack of a better word*.

Answer (score 1):

Our answer is: PVR.  Record the news, watch it after the kids go to bed.

Comment: This could also lend itself to screening the news for content prior to letting the kids watch it. It would be more work, but it could help parents to prepare for potential questions or discussions.