# When should a child see Star Wars: A New Hope

Tags: age-appropriate, television

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you decide if a movie is suitable for young children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-do-you-decide-if-a-movie-is-suitable-for-young-children)

And knowing that different children will react differently, what factors would make an difference to the age.

Comment: This question seems both too vague and too specific at the same time.

Comment: As Sarato says, it's too specific in that you're asking about one title; at the same time, you don't list any criteria that are important to you.

Comment: you don't need criteria to understand this very general question. it's a light and fluffy question about light and fluffy things. it can be answered in a light and fluffy manner.

Comment: Also, I don't get the downvotes. No, it's not as impactful as breast rejection or young girls wearing make-up, but if thought of as a more general question ("any thoughts on when i should expose my child to my favorite pop-culture media?") it's perfectly valid. Yeah some of the topics here are pretty serious, but not everything has to be so high minded.

Comment: @monsto, that is an excellent re-wording of the title that would likely garner more upvotes and no downvotes.

Comment: I like the question and I'll upvote if it's reworded, as it stands it's vague.  There are similar TV show questions already here that would give a good format for rewording like the Doctor Who or Terrorism questions

Comment: Reason for closing: We want to avoid having a separate question for every movie ever made, and we already have a question that is relevant to all movies.

Comment: One thing is for sure. Do not tell them Vader is Luke's father or that Princess Leia is his sister. It is vital he/she learns these the natural way. It is also important to your child's development that they view the films in their order of release OR the hatchet sequence which is IV,V,II,III,VI. Notice that episode I is absent (it is better left as supplemental material alongside the animated Clone Wars series). Tell them binks hates puppies or they will be drawn to his character. Oh and no special editions. Here is a PSA on "The Star Wars Talk" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCjMGOvMghY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general i agree with certain things in the other posts:

- 6-8 age range
- simple movie themes
- you are the parent, it's up to you to decide.

The one thing I want to add that nobody has touched on: don't jam it down their throat.

My boys (now 20, 18, 8) all loved the original trilogy. My girls (10, 6) are aware of the universe (what middle class kid wouldn't be) while also being uninterested.

The point: One of the options available is not showing it to them at all. It's entirely possible that they're just not into space adventures. Maybe they'll like Twilight.

Comment: +1 for not jamming it down their throats, our children may come from us but that doesn't mean they will like the same things we do.

Answer (score 4):

How can we know how your child will react? You know your child best.

Do you think they'd a) understand it? b) get unduly upset by any scenes in it?

If the answers are "yes" and "no" then let them watch it.

If the answers are "no" and "no" still let them watch it.

How have they reacted to similar films? It is a fairy story - brave would be knight goes on a quest to rescue the princess. Has to fight dragons and evil magicians.

Good triumphs over evil.

Comment: Yeah i think this is a good summary of the 4-6 trilogy.

Answer (score 3):

When they are able to sit through it and comprehend the story. For most kids that might be 6 or 8. I don't think there is anything inappropriate for children above 6. The violence is "stylized", and the themes are simple and compelling. I think the same for Empire Strikes Back and Return of the Jedi.

The prequels, however, I would avoid until 10 or so.

I also love the VW commercial ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R55e-uHQna0

Answer (score 1):

IMDB lists the age certifications a movie has received in many countries. This can act as a good guidance about movies you haven't seen.

Here is the ones for Star Wars:

Iceland:L (special edition) / Iceland:LH (original version) (video re-rating) / Malaysia:U / Canada:G (British Columbia/Quebec) / South Korea:All / Brazil:Livre / South Africa:PG / Netherlands:12 (DVD rating) / Italy:T / Argentina:Atp / Australia:PG / Canada:PG (Manitoba/Ontario) / Canada:PG (Nova Scotia) (special edition) / Chile:TE / Denmark:11 (special edition) / Denmark:12 / Finland:K-12 (original rating) / Finland:K-8 (special edition) / France:U / Germany:6 (special edition) / Hong Kong:I / Iceland:L (original rating) / Ireland:G / Mexico:AA / Netherlands:AL / New Zealand:PG / Norway:11 (special edition) / Norway:12 / Peru:PT / Portugal:M/12 / Singapore:PG (special edition) / Spain:T / Sweden:11 / UK:U / USA:PG (certificate #24925) / West Germany:12 (original rating) / Canada:A (Nova Scotia) (original rating)

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/parentalguide#certification

Comment: Although a big IMDB fan, i did not know about this section.